# Two lines of similar code, one works, the other doesn't. Why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, syntax

I have these two lines:

```
$target_box.children('a.ajax_trigger_title').addClass('opened_post_title');
jQuery('#'+$target_box.attr('id')+' a.ajax_trigger_title').addClass('opened_post_title');
```

The first line doesn't work, but the second one does. Why?

Here's the relevant HTML if you must know:

```
<div class="box" id="30" style="position: absolute; left: 350px; top: 0px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px; ">
    <h2>
        <a class="ajax_trigger_title" id="open_30" href="http://keepskatinbro.com/2011/01/20/some-highlights-from-ksbs-throw-down-show-down/" rel="30">
            <span>Highlights from KSB’s “Throw Down Show Down”.</span>
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

$target_box is the div with the class of ".box"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because .children() only selects the immediate children.  Where as "#X Y" selects all descendants Y of element with ID X.

Comment: Oh, i see! So is there someway to rewrite line #1 so that it starts with `$target_box.` for intents of having code that is more readble?

Comment: @trusktr Replace `children` with `find`

Answer (score 2):

replace  "children" in `$target_box.children` with `$target_box.find`

children selects immediate children while find looks/finds inside the node!!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `$target_box` as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context):

```
$('a.ajax_trigger_title', $target_box).addClass(...);
```

(Yes this violates OP's comment *"So is there someway to rewrite line #1 so that it starts with $target_box. for intents of having code that is more readble?"* Didn't see it until after I posted.)